# HAProxy No server is available to handle this request

Tags: linux, apache, server, backend, haproxy

I have HAProxy setup on `192.46.209.80`, on port 541 I bound the HAProxy frontend.
And on the same server I am running my apache server as well.

This is my **/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg**

```
 #HAProxy for web servers
    frontend web-frontend
      bind 192.46.209.80:541
      mode http
      default_backend web-backend
    
    backend web-backend
      balance roundrobin
      server server1 192.46.209.80 check port 80
      server server2 192.46.209.82 check port 80
```

But I am getting 503 service not available.

**Note :** My question is different from the one already asked because I am serving apache and HAProxy on the same machine. `192.46.209.80`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't configure port for backend, so it connects to port used for connection to frontend, which is 541.
`server server1 192.46.209.80 check port 80` configures port 80 as port for health checks only.
Try `server server1 192.46.209.80:80 check port 80`.